# MQTT: Broker sending new message before sending the publish_complete message of the previous publish to the client

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, mqtt-vernemq

Currently I have a client that's been running on our own mqtt stack. We are currently able to process one message at a time and then ready to accept or process another message. The broker we are using is mosquitto. There are two scenarios I am facing currently.

1. After some hundreds of successful publishes and receiving messages in client. Broker publishes a new message to me before sending me the publish complete of the previous publish.
2. Broker sends me many mqtt messages in a single tcp packet which is an overload for my system to process.

Can anyone help me in setting some configuration in the broker so that the broker can send one message and wait until it sends pubcomp to send another message?

NOTE: I have already tried setting max_inflight_messages to 1 and max_queue_limit to 1

Comment: What QOS level are you subscribing at?

Comment: i am subscribing at qos 0 @hardillb

Comment: You shouldn't be sending PUBACK for QOS0 http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718041